# Use of VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT in LunarG's Tutorial

Tags: vulkan

I am struggling to understand why in the LunarG tutorial they make use of `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` for the wait semaphore in queue submission. See [section 15 of the tutorial](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.1.82.1/windows/tutorial/html/15-draw_cube.html).

They also show an example of use as wait stage for a barrier.

My problem with telling Vulkan to wait on the semaphore at the end of the pipeline it is that it seems to allow execution of all stages; while in fact since the framebuffer is not ready, you really should not do anything else beyond vertex shading.

See also [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496573/415727), which seems to agree that `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` does not make sense for the second synchronization context (and similarly `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE` does not make sense for the first synchronization context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, using `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` as the wait stage for the wait semaphore is wrong. It should be `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` or earlier, so that the layout transition (from `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` at the beginning of the renderpass) and write to the fragment color outputs are blocked until the semaphore is signaled.

Comment: Filed an issue with LunarG: https://vulkan.lunarg.com/issue/view/5b8c86ede46ffe5cf54ed303.

Comment: Their renderpass does not seem to have any explicit dependencies, so I think it should be `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` (i.e. `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT` to chain with the implicit renderpass). Though that is extremely confusing way to programm in a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing out this problem.  We've updated the tutorial and the update will appear on the LunarXchange website no later than the next SDK release.
edit: fix spelling.