# Understanding the Execution Duration under PIX 2303.30

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11, directx-12

I am profiling my renderer to do some optimization.
To help me I use PIX 2303.30 and I successfully get captures. But when I select a cell inside the timeline I get two values:

- Duration
- TOP to EOP.

[image]

What is the meaning of each?

Comment: Duration is actual kernel execution I believe, TOP/EOP stands for top/end of pipeline. DirectX12 abstracts away pipeline stuff I believe, that is more exposed in vulkan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495580/vulkan-top-bottom-of-pipe-and-all-commands You'll have to get Chuck to explain pipelines i.e. why consecutive compute shaders have the same TOP values